# Checking if string begins with another string?

Tags: javascript, string

I have the code that follows. The goal is to check if the Name variable starts with TBD. If it does the whole variable will be populated to another location. However, if and only if it starts with "TBD - Hot" will it be treated differently.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

if ("%%%Name%%%"=="TBD")  {document.write('<iframe width="100%" height="550" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src=""></iframe>');
}
else if ("%%%Name%%%"=="TBD - HOT")  {document.write('<iframe width="100%" height="550" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src=""></iframe>');
}
else {document.write('<iframe width="100%" height="550" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src=""></iframe>');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) is what you are seeking

```
if (str.indexOf('TBD - HOT') === 0) {

} else if (str.indexOf('TBD') === 0) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be [String.prototype.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) which [is faster in some browsers](http://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-indexof/12):

```
if (str.substring(0, 9) === "TBD - HOT") {

}
else if (str.substring(0, 3) === "TBD") {

}
else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use RegExp in here

```
if ((/^(TBD - HOT).*/).test(str) === 0) {

} else if ((/^(TBD).*/).test(str) === 0) {

} else {

}
```